# Javascript - return false error

Tags: javascript

I have a form validation function that loops through the form elements checking for empty fields - code below:

```
function formValidate(ourform){
  var formelems = document.getElementById(ourform).elements;

  for (var i=0; i<formelems.length; i++){
  if(formelems[i].value == "") {
   alert("Empty Field(s). Please fill in all the fields.");
   return false;
    }   
  }    
}
```

the problem is that my form does not return false if there's an empty field - it processes the form. I have solved this before but now i just cannot remember how.

Thanks.

Comment: Paste the full javascript, question is not clear

Comment: Your code has been stripped, please paste it again with code sample button applied to it

Comment: also use formatting ....

Comment: formElements[].type would very useful for you ...

Comment: Sorry guys i'm new and still getting familiar with the tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the answer is that in your example, you aren't actually returning anything.  In Pandiya's example he is returning true/false depending on the conditions.  Remember to also use a return statement in whatever even call you are using, probably in your example it would be

```
<form blah blah blah onsubmit="return formValidate(this)">
```

Comment: How dumb of me, i forgot to add the 'return' part in my form. Thanks Jon.

Comment: no problem man, I've done that stuff so many times.  stare at a piece of code for too long and you're unable to look at it with fresh eyes.  you going to mark the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hai try this,

```
function checkForEmpties(form) {
var i;
var formElements = form.elements;


for (i=0; i<formElements.length; i++) 
    {
    if (formElements[i].type == "text") {
        if (formElements[i].value != "") {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (formElements[i].type == "checkbox") {
        if (formElements[i].checked) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    } 

}
return false;
    }
```